# trying to implement two constructors with arrays of String and URL as parameters gives an ambiguous error

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, overloading

I am implementing class named ClasspathDiscoverer and have two constructors with signatures as shown below.

```
public class ClasspathDiscoverer {

public ClasspathDiscoverer() {

}

public ClasspathDiscoverer(String[] paths) {

}

public ClasspathDiscoverer(URL[] urls) {

}
}
```

Compiling this gives me an error as below and I am a bit clueless as to why java would confuse an array of Strings with an array of URLs ?

reference to ClasspathDiscoverer is ambiguous both constructor ClasspathDiscoverer(java.lang.String[]) in org.appops.scanner.ClasspathDiscoverer and constructor ClasspathDiscoverer(java.net.URL[]) in org.appops.scanner.ClasspathDiscoverer match

Can some one please help me understand ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your constructors. The problem is where you initialize the class object whereelse in your code. Looks like you are sending a `null` object. It can't be predicted which constructor you wonna use.

Try the following maybe:

```
String[] paths = null;
new ClasspathDiscoverer(paths);
```

Comment: to bypass the issue I added a dummy boolean to one of the constructors though I guess I could design the whole thing better.

Comment: No, I dont think that is the solution. try the code I suggested when you initialize your object.